# How do I force a textbox in an Access form to skip to the next textbox when a specific character is entered?

Tags: string, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 2 textboxes: job and suffix. The format looks like this.

Job: H000001501
Suffix: 0012

*However*, some of the reports we use combine both fields to make one scannable barcode, like so:

Job Number H000001501-0012

I want to allow my users to be able to either scan the barcode **or** type in the job and suffix. To do this, I need to make the job textbox skip over the hyphen ("-") when it's entered and finish inputting the suffix into the 2nd textbox. How do I do this? Would it have something to do with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub OnExitTextBox1(strInput As String)

Dim aTest() As String

aTest = Split(strInput, "-")

Me.TextBox1.value = aTest(0)
Me.TextBox2.value = aTest(1)

End Sub
```

Using the split function splits a string into an array based on a delimiter, in our case the hyphen, then you can use the array to pass to textbox1 and textbox2, the hyphen is removed, as its the delimiter, so your left with the 2 parts.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm so I guess I need something to happen as soon as the job number is scanned in. So I was looking at some stuff and I think I need either a OnKeyDown or OnKeyPress event.

Comment: So when the hyphen key is press/scanned in, the focus must go to the next textbox and continue the input there.

Comment: use SetFocus to do that.